# I have added an extra step in the checkout. How can I display products on there?

Tags: upselling

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

I have added an extra step in the check-out by installing this:

https://github.com/tmhub/suggestpage

This page comes up after the product details page.

I have spent **many (many) hours** in an effort to display products on there. The idea is *to offer up-sell products there* (I'm using the word "up-sell" as business jargon here rather than Magento terminology).

Here are my previous posts regarding this very issue. **None of the solutions suggested in them worked:**

[How to modify an existing custom page with product-specific cross-sell products so that it shows generic cross-sell products instead?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209084/how-to-modify-an-existing-custom-page-with-product-specific-cross-sell-products)

[How to add a custom page with cross-sell products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122348/how-to-add-a-custom-page-with-cross-sell-products)

### ***It is so hard for me to believe that it is so very difficult to make products appear on a page within Magento....All I need to do is display a group of products on the extra step of the check-out - I don't really care if these be products from a category, products that have the Featured attribute selected or any other way that will accomplish this.***

---

Here is my **IndexController.php** file (which dictates what shows up on the extra check-out step page):

```
class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()


{

 $this->loadLayout()
    ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
    ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');


$block2 = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block2);

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(100);
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_crosssell')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml'); $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);


$this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the group of product in the same category,
you can do this by:

phtml:

```
$rootId=$block->getRootCategory();
foreach ($block->getCategoryCollection($rootId) as $yourCategory) : 
  $yourCategoryName=$yourCategory->getName();
  $yourCategoryId=$yourCategory->getId();
    if($yourCategoryName== 'upsells'){
      foreach ($block->getCategoryCollection($yourCategoryId) as $category) :
        $catId=$category->getId();
            foreach ($block->getProductCollection($category->getId()) as $product) : 
               $upsellProductId=$check=$product->getId();

      <your html code to display product using product Id>

         endforech;
     endforech;
   }
endforech;
```

block:

```
public function getRootCategory()
{


    $rootCategoryID = NULL;
  if($this->getData('parentcat') > 0)
        $rootCategoryID = $this->getData('parentcat'); 
    else
        $rootCategoryID = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();


    return $rootCategoryID ;
}

//get children category by parent category id
public function getCategoryCollection($categoryId)
{
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
    $childCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
    return $childCategories;
}
  public function getProductCollection($categoryId)
{
 return $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
}
```

remember to finish the di.xml file.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help. My category name is "upsells" = ID: 216. I have an IndexController.php which is part of the extra step in the checkout (https://github.com/tmhub/suggestpage) plugin that controls what displays on the extra check-out step --) I will put the contents of that file up in my original post now. Would I be able to put your code for "block" in that file or do I actually have to create a Static block and then reference that in the IndexController.php file? How would I modify your code given my category name and ID? Thank you so much for helping! :o)

Comment: You can put it in your block and display your product using product id $upsellProductId in html code.
I have add more details already.